# Moving desired row to the top of pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

In `pandas`, how can I copy or move a row to the top of the Data Frame without creating a copy of the Data Frame?

For example, I managed to do almost what I want with the code below, but I have the impression that there might be a better way to accomplish this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Probe':['Test1','Test2','Test3'], 'Sequence':['AATGCGT','TGCGTAA','ATGCATG']})

df

   Probe Sequence
0  Test1  AATGCGT
1  Test2  TGCGTAA
2  Test3  ATGCATG

df_shifted = df.shift(1)

df_shifted

   Probe Sequence
0    NaN      NaN
1  Test1  AATGCGT
2  Test2  TGCGTAA


df_shifted.ix[0] = df.ix[2]

df_shifted

   Probe Sequence
0  Test3  ATGCATG
1  Test1  AATGCGT
2  Test2  TGCGTAA
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this. You don't need to make a copy of the dataframe.

```
df["new"] = range(1,len(df)+1)

   Probe Sequence  new
0  Test1  AATGCGT    1
1  Test2  TGCGTAA    2
2  Test3  ATGCATG    3


df.ix[2,'new'] = 0
df.sort_values("new").drop('new', axis=1)

   Probe Sequence
2  Test3  ATGCATG
0  Test1  AATGCGT
1  Test2  TGCGTAA
```

Basically, since you can't insert the row into the index at 0, create a column so you can.

If you want the index ordered, use this:

```
df.sort_values("new").reset_index(drop='True').drop('new', axis=1)

   Probe Sequence
0  Test3  ATGCATG
1  Test1  AATGCGT
2  Test2  TGCGTAA
```

Edit: `df.ix` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html). Here's the same method with `.loc`.

```
df["new"] = range(1,len(df)+1)
df.loc[df.index==2, 'new'] = 0
df.sort_values("new").drop('new', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Merlin. Your answer works and it is applicable to rows with index n. I prefer Kartik's approach since I prefer not to create a new column.

Comment: @ropolo, Kartiks method exactly what you said do didn't want to do that is     "without creating a copy of the Data Frame"

Comment: @ropolo Replace 2 with 'n'

Comment: That is a good point, @Merlin. The `pandas` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) say that `pd.concat` makes a full copy of the data. I wasn't aware of that. I also read in the docs that one can set `copy=False` in `pd.concat`. In the case of `pd.merge`, it seems that  `copy=False` "may improve performance / memory".  That being said, I like your approach, and since it doesn't create a copy, I will accept it.

Comment: By the way, @Merlin, would you mind providing some feedback on my own answer? Is it more expensive to add a row of NaN like in my answer, or to create a new column like in yours?

Answer (score 9):

[`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[[n],:], df.drop(n, axis=0)], axis=0)
```

Comment: can you think of an alternative approach that does not create a copy of the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I came up with a solution. By all means, please feel free to add your own answer if you think yours is better:

```
import numpy as np

df.ix[3] = np.nan

df

   Probe Sequence
0  Test1  AATGCGT
1  Test2  TGCGTAA
2  Test3  ATGCATG
3    NaN      NaN

df = df.shift(1)

   Probe Sequence
0    NaN      NaN
1  Test1  AATGCGT
2  Test2  TGCGTAA
3  Test3  ATGCATG

df.ix[0] = df.ix[2]

df

   Probe Sequence
0  Test3  ATGCATG
1  Test1  AATGCGT
2  Test2  TGCGTAA
3  Test3  ATGCATG
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that does not require a new column or `sort_values`.

With default index (`RangeIndex`):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Probe': ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
                   'Sequence': ['AATGCGT', 'TGCGTAA', 'ATGCATG']})

   Probe Sequence
0  Test1  AATGCGT
1  Test2  TGCGTAA
2  Test3  ATGCATG

to_appear_first = [2]
new_index_order = [*to_appear_first, *df.index.difference(to_appear_first)]
df.loc[new_index_order].reset_index(drop=True)

   Probe Sequence
0  Test3  ATGCATG
1  Test1  AATGCGT
2  Test2  TGCGTAA
```

With `Probe` as the index column:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Probe': ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
                   'Sequence': ['AATGCGT', 'TGCGTAA', 'ATGCATG']}).set_index("Probe")

      Sequence
Probe         
Test1  AATGCGT
Test2  TGCGTAA
Test3  ATGCATG

to_appear_first = ["Test3"]
new_index_order = [*to_appear_first, *df.index.difference(to_appear_first)]
df.loc[new_index_order]

      Sequence
Probe         
Test3  ATGCATG
Test1  AATGCGT
Test2  TGCGTAA
```