# Pandas: move row (index and values) from last to first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to move an entire row (index and values) from the last row to the first row of a DataFrame.  Every other example I can find either uses an [ordered row index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408621/add-a-row-at-top-in-pandas-dataframe) (to be specific - my `row` index is not a numerical sequence - so I cannot simply add at -1 and then reindex with +1) or [moves the values while maintaining the original index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980507/moving-desired-row-to-the-top-of-pandas-data-frame).  My DF has descriptions as the index and the values are discrete to the index description.

I'm adding a row and then would like to move that into row 1.  Here is the setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'F', 'D', 'C'],
    'col2' : [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
}).set_index('col1')

#output
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
      col2  col3
col1            
A        2     0
A        1     1
B        9     9
F        8     4
D        7     2
C        4     3
```

I then add a new row as follows:

```
df.loc["Deferred Description"] = pd.Series([''])

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
                      col2  col3
col1                            
A                      2.0   0.0
A                      1.0   1.0
B                      9.0   9.0
F                      8.0   4.0
D                      7.0   2.0
C                      4.0   3.0
Deferred Description   NaN   NaN
```

I would like the resulting output to be:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
                      col2  col3
col1                            
Defenses Description   NaN   NaN
A                      2.0   0.0
A                      1.0   1.0
B                      9.0   9.0
F                      8.0   4.0
D                      7.0   2.0
C                      4.0   3.0
```

I've tried using `df.shift()` but only the values shift.  I've also tried `df.sort_index()` but that requires the index to be ordered (there are several SO examples using `df.loc[-1] = ...` then then reindexing with `df.index = df.index + 1`).  In my case I need the `Defenses Description` to be the first row.

Comment: It is - I missed the accepted answer and was focused on the second answer.  thanks.

Comment: No problem, it appears Max and I had the same idea ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not one of cyclic shifting, but a simpler one—one of insertion (which is why I've chosen to mark this question as duplicate).

Construct an empty DataFrame and then concatenate the two using `pd.concat`.

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=['Deferred Description']), df])

                     col2 col3
Deferred Description  NaN  NaN
A                       2    0
A                       1    1
B                       9    9
F                       8    4
D                       7    2
C                       4    3
```

If this were columns, it'd have been easier. Funnily enough, pandas has a `DataFrame.insert` function that works for columns, but not rows.

---

**Generalized Cyclic Shifting**
If you were curious to know how you'd cyclically shift a dataFrame, you can use `np.roll`.

```
# apply this fix to your existing DataFrame
pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df.values, 1, axis=0), 
     index=np.roll(df.index, 1), columns=df.columns
)

                     col2 col3
Deferred Description  NaN  NaN
A                       2    0
A                       1    1
B                       9    9
F                       8    4
D                       7    2
C                       4    3
```

This, thankfully, also works when you have duplicate index values. If the index or columns aren't important, then `pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df.values, 1, axis=0))` works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `append`

```
pd.DataFrame({'col2':[np.nan],'col3':[np.nan]},index=["Deferred Description"]).append(df)
Out[294]: 
                      col2  col3
Deferred Description   NaN   NaN
A                      2.0   0.0
A                      1.0   1.0
B                      9.0   9.0
F                      8.0   4.0
D                      7.0   2.0
C                      4.0   3.0
```